# Unable to locate the Javac Compiler when compiling with maven - Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:

Tags: eclipse, maven, compiler-errors

I have compilation error on compiling with maven.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05\..\lib\tools.jar
```

So I set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable but no advantage. The error seems **maven search java compiler in jre path, not in `JAVA_HOME`.**

- `JAVA_HOME` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05`.
- Installed JRE is `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05`.
- My `PATH` variable is:

> `C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;D:\alfrescoplatform\ImageMagick;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.3-Q16;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin`

Here is my detail log

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringMVC Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ SpringMVC ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ SpringMVC ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\Learning\spring-workspace\SpringMVC2.5.6\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.719s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 01 17:22:43 MMT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/8M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project SpringMVC: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

If you have any idea about this, let me know.

Comment: Can you include the output of `mvn --version`?

Comment: (And you definitely started a *new* command window after setting `JAVA_HOME`, right?)

Comment: I am just using maven plugin with eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Your JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05

**Way 1**: The following steps would work for Eclipse:

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
2. Edit the existing JRE location as: Set JRE Home = JAVA_HOME or JAVA_HOME\jre (In your case the path should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05 OR C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\jre)
3. Click Finish and OK button

**Way 2**: Another way to set the JRE System Library:

1. Open eclipse and Right click on Eclipse project Properties
2. Java Build Path -> Libraries
3. Select JRE System Library -> Click Edit button
4. Click "Installed JREs..." button
5. Edit JRE as: Set JRE Home = JAVA_HOME or JAVA_HOME\jre

**Way 3**: The following steps should also work well:

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
2. Select the JRE you are using
3. Press Edit -> Add External JARs...
4. Browse to Java\jdk1.6.0_05\lib and select tools.jar and Press Enter
5. Click Finish and OK button

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `vm` argument to your `eclipse.ini` file.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem, tried these solutions with no success:

- [Maven Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585380/maven-unable-to-locate-the-javac-compiler-in)
- [maven build failed: Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: jre or jdk issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222560/build-failed-question-maven-jre-or-jdk-problem)

**What worked for me:**

- click the little down arrow next to the green run button [image: click]
- select *Run Configurations*
- on the *JRE* tab, select *Alternate JRE*, then select your desired target (if it's not on the list, click *Installed JREs* to add it in).