# Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in MAVEN EXPORT

Tags: java, maven

i want to Export a Java Project with maven. But i became this Error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project craftbukkit: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have alredy set my JAVA home to this Directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
```

What must i do, that it work?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585380/maven-unable-to-locate-the-javac-compiler-in)

Answer (score 0):

You can try some:

1. If you are in Eclipse you can check your installed JRE.
2. Try newer version of maven-compiler-plugin and set your source andtarget version.
3. Echo $JAVA_HOME and be sure it refers to your mentioned location.
4. Try javac a java code to be more sure about your default java compiler.
5. Use mvn package assembly:single for exporting.

Comment: Thanks it works now! How can i Update a Maven Project from the newest Source of the Github Project?

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you want. But such as any other projects you update your project by git commands, and recompile it using maven. By the way, how has your problem been solved?